# Using Composer install component return errors

Tags: yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app

I want install yii2-user component by composer . use command `composer require "dektrium/yii2-user:0.9.*@dev"`.but I get the errors:

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.phpcomposer.com/p/symfony/dom-crawler%24ca0f1f00e970
  0369080dec636093ccc7480e0fe484edd4a18c03db023518ac4f.json" file could not b
  e downloaded: SSL: Connection reset by peer
  failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

failed the:

```
https://packagist.phpcomposer.com/p/symfony/dom-crawler%24ca0f1f00e970
  0369080dec636093ccc7480e0fe484edd4a18c03db023518ac4f.json'
```

but I used command

```
curl https://packagist.phpcomposer.com/p/symfony/dom-crawler%24ca0f1f00e970
      0369080dec636093ccc7480e0fe484edd4a18c03db023518ac4f.json
```

that returned result be ok.I try to 'composer self-update' and 'composer clear chche' but error exist
can everybody help me ?

Comment: Can you run `composer diag` and post the results of the https test to packagist?

Comment: @Aiden any proxy in use?

Comment: @topher yes,that run be fine